# Как получить номер недели из даты

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Имею [датафрейм](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F5VW25ZARwA2BIveJnAj-G8dkNb6zfFQ/view?usp=sharing)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить номер недели для каждой даты, для того что бы обнаружить какие ученики пропускали недели. использую метод strftime("%V"), получаю номер недели в году, но в 2021 недели обнуляются. Для этого прибавляю для 2021 года  53, но почему-то у некоторых недель 2020 года значение 106

```
df.lesson_day_x = df.lesson_day_x.apply(lambda x: int(x.strftime("%V")) if x.strftime("%Y")=='2020' else int(x.strftime("%V")) +53)
```

Но почему-то некоторые значения в 2020 году становиться равны 106...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, почему некоторые значения равны 106? Как лучше отправлять ссылки на csv, что бы можно было открыть read_csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно изобретать велосипед, потому что

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("PostgreSQL.csv", parse_dates=["lesson_day"])
df["weeknum"] = df["lesson_day"].dt.isocalendar().week
```

проверяем:

```
print(df["weeknum"].unique())
<IntegerArray>
[41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23,
 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,
  3,  2,  1, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42]
Length: 53, dtype: UInt32
```